# Is this a genuine Nikon Lens Pen?

Tags: nikon, cleaning

I bought this branded as a Nikon Lens Pen (came in "Nikon" packaging, etc. Same price as listed on Nikon's website). Only after opening & using it did my suspicion arise, it feels cheaply manufactured and it looks very different in shape and color from what is listed on the Website.

Is this (one iteration of) the real pen, or was I sold a cheap knock-off ?

[image: Pen I bought]

Comment: Interestingly enough, the preview of the photo has a 180° rotation !?

Comment: Where did you buy it?

Comment: @AndyBlankertz Amazon

Comment: Could you provide an exact link to the product you ordered? If you bring up the invoice on amazon, the product listing should be a link that takes you top the product page.

Comment: Here is the product page: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00006JN3G/

Comment: That is the older version which may no longer be available to *Cameta Camera*, which is who you really bought it from *through* amazon.

Comment: Yup, realised that. So I received the newer version, and their Amazon listing is outdated. Thanks, I feel more confident using that on my lenses now that I know this is the original item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nikon doesn't actually manufacture the Nikon lens pen. The supplier that produces them for Nikon also markets them as the [LensPen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KO0GY6). They recently introduced a ["new and improved" version](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007G5NNOW). There are also "micro" and "mini" versions of the LensPen on the market.

Your photo looks like the newer version.

Comment: It does look very much like the new version (physically, and in functionality: screw-on cap (not click-on). Thank you for the insight

Comment: FWIW I bought the "old" version Nikon LensPen linked in my answer in 2010 and it feels like a cheap piece of plastic also.